# Can we create object Of Local class

Tags: java

I am in confusion regarding creating object of Local Class. I am not able to find out how to create Object Of local class.Please help me with this. Thanks

Comment: We will help you, if you can share your code.

Comment: Show us some code with context on what exactly you're having trouble with. Multiple types of local classes exist.

Answer (score 3):

#### Example 1

```
void method1() {
   class Local {}
   new Local(); // here!
}
```

An instance of a local class is created on Line 3 of the above code.

#### Example 2

```
void method2() {
  new Object() {}; // here!
}
```

An instance of a local class is created on Line 2 of the above code. This variant declares and instantiates an *anonymous* local class.

Answer (score 0):

Well if I understood your question correctly then this is what you are searching for arenot you?

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        class LocalClass{

        }

        LocalClass localClass = new LocalClass();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the two cases below where an instance of a local class is created - both in a **static** and **non-static** context.

```
public class TopLevelClass { // Top Level Class

    void nonStaticMethod() {
        class NonStaticLocalClass { // 1. Local Class in non-static context.
        }

        new NonStaticLocalClass();
    }

    static void staticMethod() {
        class StaticLocalClass { // 2. Local Class in static context.
        }

        new StaticLocalClass();
    }

}
```